# How do I iterate through a loop 1 by 1 adding a classList value each time an event is fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, events

I'm new to JavaScript and am wondering how to update the `classList` of each item in the `NodeList` each time the `onDocumentMouseScroll` event is fired.

By using a `for` loop I grabbed all the items I need to change and added the 'scroll' class to them using `classList.add`, but I don't know how to change them 1 by 1?

```
var slide = document.querySelectorAll('div.about-slide');
```

```
function addOnScroll() {

for  ( var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++){
  console.log(i);
  //add 'scroll' class to [0] after the wheel event then [1] then [2]...'
  slide[i].classList.add('scroll');

  };
}
```

```
function onDocumentMouseScroll( event ) {
    console.log(event);

        if( Date.now() - lastMouseWheelStep > 600 ) {

            lastMouseWheelStep = Date.now();

            var delta = event.detail || -event.wheelDelta;
            if( delta > 0 ) {
                navigateNext();
                addOnScroll() 


            }

            else if( delta < 0 ) {
                navigatePrev();
            }

        }

    }
```

I expect the result to iterate through the `NodeList` 1 by 1 rather than adding the class 'scroll' to all after 1 event.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? If you are going to iterate through them all, it's going to add the class to all of them? Or is that just a stopgap until you get it more how you wanted? Just trying to make sure I understand your question properly.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply you are a legend! Yes, it's a stopgap, as I'm not really sure where to go next. So, when the onDocumentMouseScroll if fired I'd like to add the class name 'scrolled' to the [0] of NodeList and the next time it's fired I'd like to add it to [1] and so on until it reaches the end of the index.

Comment: Note that the `scroll` event occurs many, many times as a user scrolls through a document. So even if you "fix" this, you may see the class get added to all of them so rapidly that it might as well be all at once. You probably need to "debounce" the event, or only add the class if the user has scrolled a certain percent of the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your addOnScroll function, so that you can check for next item without scroll class and add scroll class to item and break the loop.

```
function addOnScroll() {
    for  ( var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++){
        if(slide[i].classList.contains('scroll')){
            continue;
        }else{
            slide[i].classList.add('scroll');
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully you absolute legend! You deserve all of the wonders of this world!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to keep track of the last item you've added the 'scroll' class to and iterate.

```
let lastI = 0;

function addOnScroll() {
  if (i < slide.length)
    slide[i].classList.add('scroll');
  lastI++;
}
```

Alternatively, this problem seems suited for generators, but that's a bit harder to read imo:

```
let slideIterator = (function* () {
  for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++)
    yield slide[i];
})();

function addOnScroll() {
  let slide = slideIterator.next().value;
  if (slide)
    slide.classList.add('scroll');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are a gift to this world!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `:not(.scroll)` to your query:

```js
function addOnScroll() {
  const item = document.querySelector('div.about-slide:not(.scroll)');
  if (item != null) {
    item.classList.add('scroll');
  } else {
    // no items left, do something?
  }
}
```